# Not able to run selenium test cases on monzilla firefox 26.0

Tags: java, eclipse, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I have recorded test cases on selenium IDE (2.8.0) on monzilla firefox 26.0.Now I am not able to run it by using selenium standalone jars. The jars that I am using to run test cases are:-
junit-4.10.jar
selenium-java-client-driver.jar
selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar
testng-6.2.jar

java version:- jdk1.7.0_55

eclipse version-Version: 3.3.0

As per my understanding, it is compatibility issue.please help.
Thanks

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Use latest JARS version 2.44.0 for selenium JARs.

Comment: for what it is worth, Selenium released 2.45 a few days ago: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/